Blazor Server failing with unexpected query parameters
I have a Blazor web app with an index page at the route "/".
When accessed through myhost/myapp everything works fine. However, I published the url in a Facebook post and when users tap that link FB appends a query parameter called fbclid - making the Blazor app fail.
The error message I get in the web server logs is "The URI 'http://myhost/myapp?fbclid=[...]' is not contained by the base URI 'http://myhost/myapp/'."
My Blazor page was like this:
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

To handle the issue, I tried adding a query argument like this:
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "fbclid")]
    public string FacebookClientId { get; set; }
}

... but the error remains.
What should I do differently?

Are these the literl URLs?  Are you sure you are on http and not on https ?

From the routing point of view, http or https shouldn't make a difference, right?
To answer the question: yes, in this case I was using http. Without the query string the page responds as expected, with the query string it returns the error.

And are you sure the error mentions 'http' as well?  Any way it's a hosting config problem, not a Blazor one.

"it's a hosting config problem, not a Blazor one" - why do you think so? Route matching is Blazor, isn't it?

Blazor would have shown the "nothing here page".

Well, NavigationManager is a Blazor component, isn't it? Just adding more detail on the exception thrown:
Exception:
System.ArgumentException: The URI 'http://myhost/myapp?fbclid=132' is not contained by the base URI 'http://myhost/myapp/'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.Validate(Uri baseUri, String uri)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager.Initialize(String baseUri, String uri)

Interesting observation: if I use an incorrect (?) url like http://myhost/myapp/?fbclid=123 (note the "/" character in front of the "?" then the error goes away znd the page is displayed. So http://myhost/myapp and http://myhost/myapp/?fbclid=123 both work OK, but http://myhost/myapp?fbclid=123 produces the error.

Then the  error msg in the Q is better then the one in the comments here.

Sorry, I don't get your point. The question is how to solve it? a URL with a '?' spearating the query string is valid in HTTP terms. How do I change my Blazor app to accept it?
